# Why I can't rename a file that is in use

Tags: windows, operating-system

I just wounder why I can't rename a file that is opened, or in use by other program? 
what is the purpose of that ?

Comment: What do you think would happen if the other program saved the file after you renamed it?

Comment: It will save the changes on the same file with the new name !

Answer (score 4):

The question is based on a false premise, you most certainly **can** rename a file that is in use on common file systems that are used on Windows.  There is very little a process can do to prevent this, short from changing the ACL on the file to deny access.  That is exceedingly rare.

Locking a file protects the file data, not the file metadata.

This feature has many uses, most notably the [ReplaceFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function depends on it.  Which is the way a program can save a file even if another process has it locked.

The one thing you *cannot* do is rename the file to move it to a different drive.  Because that requires much more work then simply altering or moving the directory entry of the file.  It also requires copying the file data from one drive to another.  That of course is going to fail when the file data is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Because file currently in use. You cannot change the name of the file. 
when file is opened it's process is created. you can not change the name of process at runtime. 
Hope question perfectly answered

Answer (score 0):

It's a design decision resulting is less complicated behavior. When a file `F` is opened by process `A`, you must assume `A` works with the name of `F` as with useful information, e.g. displays it to the user, passes it around to some other process, stores it in configuration, MRU list, whatever, etc. Hence if process `B` renamed `F`, process `A` would now work with invalid information. Hence it is generally safer to disallow such manipulations.